# Open two browser instances in one Browserstack session

Tags: java, testing, junit, browserstack, selenide

Using **Selendie** I do next:

1. Open browser with disabled cookies
2. Make some steps
3. Close browser
4. Open a new browser instance
5. Make some steps

3rd and 4th steps implementation:

```
WebDriverRunner.getWebDriver().close();
WebDriver webDriver = TestConfig.getWebDriver(getDisabledCookiesPreferences(COOKIES_STATUS));
WebDriverRunner.setWebDriver(webDriver);
```

Browserstack session ID equals to `(RemoteWebDriver driver).getSessionID()`;

As result, in BrowserStack I get 2 sessions: for both WebDriver instances. Can I somehow open the browser a second time in the same session? Or maybe you know a way how toset up a new browser instance with a predefined session ID (from old instance)?

Answer (score 0):

I think after 1 and 2 steps you should switch to another tab and perform step It will remain in the same session.

Comment: Enabling cookies back does not work in this case. So I must close and create a new driver.